# 3ware raid controller, unit unusable, several degraded disks

Tags: raid, 3ware, raid6, degraded

I was switching the disk drives in my server, running RAID 6 on 5 disks on a 3ware 9650SE controller, for newer disks and have run into a problem.
The two first disks went fine, I took out one disk and inserted a new one, let the array rebuild and repeated for disk 2.
When booting after switching the 3. disk I noticed two where wmissing, not just the one, so I did not ask the controller to rebuild, but shut it off and investigated.
One of the remaining disks had a bad power connector, so I took out that disk and put in the one I had just taken out.
When booting again booth of the disks originally being a part of the array shows as #degraded"
The two disks that was synced in are ok and the las swapped disk is "spare".
With 2 of 5 degraded and one missing I can't rebuild.
Why are the two disks marked as degraded and whan, if anything, can I do to get them online again?
Both disks are ok according to SMART...

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Trash the RAID set, rebuild it from scratch and restore from backups.

Comment: There has been written absolutely nothing to the disks after the last time the array was operational, so the data is there, but there's no way to force the controller to rebuild?

This IS the backup and it takes a looooong time to start it from scratch, again, so I would very much like to find an alternative.

Hardware controllers :sigh: I have never lost an array with mdadm...